# How to programmatically change the desktop background in Windows 10 using Python?

Tags: python, windows-10

I'm trying to change the desktop background in my Windows 10 PC using a Python script but all I'm getting is a plain blue screen (default wallpaper I guess). Here is the code I'm using -

```
import ctypes
import os

pathToBmp = os.path.normpath("C:/Users/Siddharth/Wallpapers/a.bmp")
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, pathToBmp, 0)
```

The script works for my Windows XP system, but fails to do so in Windows 10.
The path to BMP file is absolute, I've checked it multiple times during debugging, however I'm still getting a blue screen.
Any fix?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: Then yeah, that dupe is what you need.

Comment: Perfect. This worked. Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: You can make an answer out of that if you want. I did a thousand google searches before this question but couldn't find a workable answer. This might help someone in future